# swift: method contain "NSMutableArray" does't override

Tags: objective-c, swift

When I am trying to create a new Swift class based on an objective C;

I found that an method contain NSMutableArray doesn't called; Some of other override method are okay;

Here are the code segment of those:

**Parent Class**

```
- (void)setMenuArray:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
   NSLog(@"Default SetMenu Logic");
}
```

**Child Class**

```
func setMenuArray(menuArray : NSMutableArray) {     
    menuArray.add("test1");
    menuArray.add("test2");
    NSLog("Override setMenuArray Logic");
    NSLog("%@", menuArray);
}
```

What is come back is that the ChildClass.setMenuArray isn't called but called the ParentClass version:

like this:

```
2016-12-22 10:22:08.941 Taped[9787:410028] Before SetMenu
2016-12-22 10:22:08.941 Taped[9787:410028] Default SetMenu Logic
2016-12-22 10:22:08.942 Taped[9787:410028] getMenuArray: called
2016-12-22 10:22:08.943 Taped[9787:410028] After SetMenu
```

It is fine for those method doesn't have any parameter

Another thing is that when I tried add "override" prefix, it show a compile error "method doesn't override ..."

Comment: How are the parent class and the child class declared? Please show that code.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3, Objective-C method `- (void)setMenuArray:(NSMutableArray *)array` is imported as `func setMenuArray(_ array: NSMutableArray!)`.

You need to specify that the first parameter does not have an argument label with `_` ([SE-0046](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0046-first-label.md)).

Try changing the method header of your **Child Class** to:

```
override func setMenuArray(_ menuArray : NSMutableArray!) {
```